# How to analyse the relationship between many categorical variables

Tags: spss, categorical-data, predictor

I have a number of categorical variables, each with varying numbers of levels:

gender of client (m,f)
age group (0-8, etc.)
diagnosis (mild, moderate, severe, profound)
location (community, residential)
restrictive interventions used (physical restraint, chemical restraint, seclusion, etc.)
(and more)

I want to see if certain group characteristics, e.g. a client's age or gender (or both combined) are more predictive than others of receiving a particular restrictive intervention.

E.g. Does gender predict type of restrictive intervention received more strongly than range of diagnosis? What is the strongest predictor of seclusion?

I'm pretty much at a loss in terms of what test to use to answer these questions.

I'm at a basic level of statistics, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A simple start could be to run a logistic regression for each intervention (physical restraint yes = 1 vs no = 0) using gender, age group etc. as predictors. More complicated techniques include baseline multinomial regression or multivariate logistic regression.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I might go for this. I had restrictive interventions with 5 levels: physical, mechanical, chemical, seclusion, other- but breaking them into separate individual variables might make things easier.